# Recover Activity from other app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `AboutActivity` that have 2 buttons that open the browser, it works fine, but when I tap the `Back Button` in the browser it goes to `Home Screen` and my app restarts to the `MainActivity`, I dont have a `finish()` in the intent method on the `AboutActivity`, how I can solve this issue.

This is the method that start de browser

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_about_github_icon:
            //este intent lanza la pagina web de github de skintigth
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://github.com/skintigth"));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_about_gplus_icon:
            //este instent lanza el perfil de google plus de skintigth
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent2.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/+rurickmaqueo"));
            intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: try using `startActivityForResult` and pass intent to return `onBackPressed`

Comment: please remover `intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` because when you add this flag then your previous activity stack is clear